# Interop Excel C#: Saving charts sheets in windows server 2008

Tags: c#, interop, com-interop, office-interop, excel-interop

I'm working on a document (`ppt, pptx, xls, xlsx, doc, docx and pdf`) splitter and overall, I made it work. Now I'm facing a final problem, the thing is that everything works just fine in my computer (windows 7 64b + office 2007), but I'm having one issue with `xlsx` in my server (windows server 2008 64b + office 2007).

The issue is that, meanwhile I'm splitting a xlsx (it works with xls) that have charts, I can create new files out of every sheet but from the ones that are charts.

```
Excel.Workbook newWork = workbooks.Add();
work.Sheets[counter].Copy(newWork.Sheets[1]);

foreach (Excel.Worksheet newSheet in newWork.Worksheets)
{
    if (newSheet.Index > 1)
    {
        newSheet.Delete();
    }
}
newWork.SaveAs(
    currentName, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookDefault, 
    Type.Missing, Type.Missing, false, false,
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange,
    Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

newWork.Close();
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(newWork);
```

newWork.SaveAs is throwing **ComException: Document not saved**. It works if I do the job manually (I mean, if I open the xlsx file and then I move/copy the chart to a new workbook). Also, if I remove the property `excelApp.DisplayAlerts = false;` it gets stuck with the dialog "save as" (If I try to finish the process manually by selecting a destination folder the "save as" popup comes up over and over again).

Any idea?